# Using Time struct in a legion system

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a system using `legion` as a ecs library.
There is an example about this in the official [documentation](https://docs.rs/legion/0.4.0/legion/#systems).

```
#[system(for_each)]
fn update_positions(pos: &mut Position, vel: &Velocity, #[resource] time: &Time) {
    pos.x += vel.dx * time.elapsed_seconds;
    pos.y += vel.dy * time.elapsed_seconds;
}
```

My problem is, that i don't know where the `Time` struct comes from. Has anybody an idea where the `Time` struct comes from and how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same as with Velocity and Position. These are structs defined by you. In the documentation, Velocity and Position are defined at the beginning. I guess they just forgot about the Time struct. Couldn't find the source for the documentation, but found something in the lib [here](https://github.com/amethyst/legion/blob/dfafc491b1577dba571d36f53eff3ad8312100f3/codegen/src/lib.rs#L96). Guess Time is just

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Time {
    elapsed_seconds: f32,
}
```

as Velocity and Position are similar

Comment: Oh, it's really that simple. Thanks a lot :)
Just one more Questions: How and where do i updated the elapsed seconds?